# \usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} and missing numbering

Tags: numbering, chapters, fncychap

I created my thesis using `\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}` for chapters. Sadly not all chapters of the parts are numbered. It's quite odd that in part I, chapters 1-2 are numbered but 4-5 are not. In part two and three no chapter is numbered.
Does anybody know how this could happen? I'm new to tex and actually used the settings of my friend's thesis, but he himself got them from sb else, so he can be of no assistance to me.
In case other infos are needed, please let me know but be specific about what you need - I'm still learning :)

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Are there any errors in the `.log` file?

Comment: Are the unnumbered chapters starred? (`\chapter*`)

Comment: What about chapter 3 in part one? Is there a point where all chapters before are numberd and all chapters after are not? If so, what have you done in that chapter? Could you have changed any of the following commands: `\thechapter` `\ChNumVar` or `\CNoV`?